# Excel vba Shape Paste not work

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to paste textbox from sheet1 to sheet2

```
Function footer()
Application.Volatile True
r = Application.Caller.Address
SheetName = Application.Caller.Parent.Name

    Select Case Range("Locale").Value
        Case "RU": boxx = Range("company").Value & Range("Locale")
        Case "EN": boxx = Range("company").Value & Range("Locale")
    End Select
Worksheets("Translations").Shapes(boxx).Copy
MsgBox Worksheets("Translations").Shapes(boxx).TextFrame.Characters.Text
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Function
```

Msgbox Looks ok but paste function do nothing, i tryed different ways

- ActiveSheet.range("A1").Paste
- ActiveSheet.range("A1").PasteSpecial
- Worksheets(SheetName).Paste
- Worksheets(SheetName).Range(r).Paste

All not working, just nothing appears in the sheet, whats is wrong?

Comment: If you are calling this function from a cell, it won't work. A UDF in a cell can't copy a shape.

Comment: yes it  calling from cell

Comment: Then it won't work, as I said. A UDF is not allowed to do that. I will post a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't copy and paste a shape, you can add a new shape and copy the text and formatting from the original - for example:

```
Function footer()
    Dim boxx                  As String
    Dim shpTo                 As Shape
    Dim shpFrom               As Shape

    Application.Volatile True

    Select Case Range("Locale").Value
        Case "RU": boxx = Range("company").Value & Range("Locale")
        Case "EN": boxx = Range("company").Value & Range("Locale")
    End Select
    Set shpFrom = Worksheets("Translations").Shapes(boxx)
    With Application.Caller
        Set shpTo = .Worksheet.Shapes.AddShape(shpFrom.AutoShapeType, .Left, .Top, shpFrom.Width, shpFrom.Height)
        shpTo.TextFrame.Characters.Text = shpFrom.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    End With
    shpFrom.PickUp
    shpTo.Apply
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already tryed this way, it not seems to me as it remove all formatings in text

Answer (score 1):

Try this copy method

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array(shpFrom.Name)).Select
Selection.Copy
```